# How can I get the parent Popup for a UIElement?

Tags: silverlight, popup, uielement

I have two questions on markup below:

```
<Popup>
    <Button x:Name="button"/>
</Popup>
```

1. Why does `VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(button)` return null?
2. How can I get the parent `Popup` for `UIElement`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Because the `Button` is only added to the visual tree when the popup is being displayed.
2. Hmm... tricky ...

**Edit**

There is an assumption in the following that your popup is defined in the XAML of `UserControl` so whilst its child may not be in the visual tree the popup primitive control is.

Re-using some code I've posted before (I really must get me a blog).

```
public static class VisualTreeEnumeration
{
    public static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> Descendents(this DependencyObject root)
    {
        int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(root);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(root, i);
            yield return child;
            foreach (var descendent in Descendents(child))
                yield return descendent;
        }
    }
}
```

This adds an extension method to the `DependencyObject` which uses the `VisualTreeHelper` to unify the search for objects added in the visual tree.  So in the usercontrol code behind you can do this:-

```
var popup this.Descendents()
        .OfType<Popup>()
        .Where(p => p.Child == button)
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

This will find the `Popup` which is the parent of "button".

Comment: Even with opened popup GetParent method returns null

Comment: Hmm... yes that is true, it is at the top of a tree which is displayed on top the existing visuals.  Hence the Offsets being relative the Silverlight control itself.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of going through the `VisualTree`, have you just tried a while loop to walk up the .Parents for the elements?

```
    private void TryClosePopupParent(object o)
    {
        while (o != null)
        {
            Popup p = (o as Popup);
            if(p == null)
            {
                o = (o as FrameworkElement).Parent;
            }
            else 
            {
                p.IsOpen = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I haven't ever tested it on something that *doesn't* have a `PopUp` as a parent, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

`Popup` control is very annoying sometimes. And I have no idea at the moment why `VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(button)` returns null. But for the second [this](http://www.hardcodet.net/2008/02/find-wpf-parent) may help.

Answer (score 1):

zihotki's solution looks promising (i haven't tested it).

Although `VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(button)` returns null, you can use `button.Parent`, which should give you the popup object.

Comment: @DaveClemmer: wow - is there a badge for editing the question and every single answer?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `PopUp` is attached to the `VisualTree`. Find more information on this  in the Remarks section
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup(v=vs.95).aspx