# How to change DatePicker default 'level'?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-toolkit

When using the Silverlight **DatePicker**, it opens on days view by default. When a user has to select his birthday, it would be a lot user-friendly if he could first select the year and drill down immediately without going up the tree first. I can guess that about 70% of our users won't even figure out how to use the calendar headers to go 'up', so if I could avoid this, it would be lovely.

Is there a way to manipulate which level the datepicker opens on by default?

Is there more user friendly control in Silverlight to select birthday?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the face of it you should be able to do something like this:-

```
        <sdk:DatePicker Name="datePicker1" >
            <sdk:DatePicker.CalendarStyle>
                <Style TargetType="sdk:Calendar">
                    <Setter Property="DisplayMode" Value="Decade" />
                </Style>
            </sdk:DatePicker.CalendarStyle>
        </sdk:DatePicker>
```

For pretty much all other features of the calendar displayed in the dropdown this would work.  However code internal to the DataPicker will set `DisplayMode` to `Month` whenever the dropdown is opened.  So we need to resort to an ugly hack:-

```
private void datePicker1_CalendarOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    DatePicker picker = (DatePicker)sender;

    if (!picker.SelectedDate.HasValue)
    {
        var popup = picker.Descendents().OfType<Popup>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (popup != null)
        {
            var item = popup.Child.Descendents().OfType<Calendar>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (item != null)
                item.DisplayMode = CalendarMode.Decade;
        }
    }
}
```

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020842/get-radiobuttons-of-group-in-silverlight-3/2022240#2022240) for my implementation of the `Descendents` extension method.

Comment: Great Answer! Thanks a lot AnthonyWJones