# How can I find selected radiobutton from defined group of radiobutton

Tags: c#, silverlight

I hv taken 4 radiobuttons and defined one group for all. And I want to find text of selected radiobutton in that group. How to code for this. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By modifying a bit [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020842/get-radiobuttons-of-group-in-silverlight-3) post you will get what you want

As that post says, add this class to your project

```
public static class VisualTreeEnumeration 
{ 
   public static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> Descendents(this DependencyObject root) 
   { 
     int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(root); 
     for (int i=0; i < count; i++) 
     { 
       var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(root, i); 
       yield return child; 
       foreach (var descendent in Descendents(child)) 
         yield return descendent; 
     } 
   } 
}
```

And this will give you result you want

```
List<RadioButton> group = this.Descendents()
                               .OfType<RadioButton>()
                               .Where(r => r.GroupName == "aaa" && r.IsChecked == true)
                               .ToList();
```

Comment: how could any one find a selected radiobutton from group (group name is aaa) of radiobuttons

Comment: see edited post @Anil, and don't forget to mark as answer if anyone helps you, or no one will answer to your questions in the future

Comment: Just wanted to add that for me, the radio button IsChecked property returns a nullable bool (bool?) and have to check if it is equal to true or not. I.E. myRadioButton.IsChecked == true.

Answer (score 1):

[From MSDN's RadioButton Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.radiobutton%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

> The following example shows two panels
>   that contain three radio buttons each.
>   One radio button from each panel are
>   grouped together. The remaining two
>   radio buttons on each panel are not
>   grouped explicitly, which means they
>   are grouped together since they share
>   the same parent control. When you run
>   this sample and select a radio button,
>   a TextBlock displays the name of the
>   group, or "grouped to panel" for a
>   radio button without an explicit group
>   name, and the name of the radio
>   button.

**XAML**

```
<TextBlock Text="First Group:"  Margin="5" />
<RadioButton x:Name="TopButton" Margin="5" Checked="HandleCheck"
     GroupName="First Group" Content="First Choice" />
<RadioButton x:Name="MiddleButton" Margin="5" Checked="HandleCheck"
     GroupName="First Group" Content="Second Choice" />
<TextBlock Text="Ungrouped:" Margin="5" />
<RadioButton x:Name="LowerButton" Margin="5" Checked="HandleCheck"
    Content="Third Choice" />
<TextBlock x:Name="choiceTextBlock" Margin="5" />
```

**Code Behind**

```
private void HandleCheck(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton rb = sender as RadioButton;
    choiceTextBlock.Text = "You chose: " + rb.GroupName + ": " + rb.Name;
}
```